# How do I manually implement the Copy trait for struct containing String?

Tags: rust

I am attempting to implement the `Copy` trait for a struct that contains a `String`. However, I am having some trouble finding relevant documentation.

Here's what I have:

```
pub struct Token {
    pub token: String,
    pub tok_type: AnotherStruct, // implements Copy/Clone already
}

impl Copy for Token { }
```

which refuses to compile, stating that I cannot implement trait `Copy` for type `String`.

I changed the `impl` to:

```
impl Copy for Token {
    fn copy(&self) -> Token {
        Token { token: self.token.clone(), tok_type: self.tok_type, }
    }
}
```

and get:

```
error[E0407]: method `copy` is not a member of trait `Copy`
  --> src/types.rs:18:5
   |
18 | /     fn copy(&self) -> Token {
19 | |         Token {
20 | |             token: self.token.clone(),
21 | |             tok_type: self.tok_type,
22 | |         }
23 | |     }
   | |_____^ not a member of trait `Copy`

error[E0204]: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type
  --> src/types.rs:17:6
   |
13 |     pub token: String,
   |     ------------------ this field does not implement `Copy`
...
17 | impl Copy for Token {
   |      ^^^^
```

Comment: Refer to the Rust book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#stack-only-data-copy Basically, you can't and shouldn't implement Copy for your types. `Copy` <=> bitwise copy, and it cannot work for non-`Copy` nested data.

Comment: So you just need Clone feature add `#[derive(Clone)]` to your structure and use `.clone()` to "copy" your data

Comment: Oh well. The main reason I wanted to implement copy for this struct is because I'm going to have to deref this struct in quite a few places, and that won't work if Copy isnt implemented.

Comment: Is there a way to *close* a SO question without deleting it?

Comment: There are several ways, actually, but it depends on your reputation and the reason for closure. I think this question is a candidate for marking as a duplicate of the question I linked; if that answers your question, you should be able to agree with the duplicate vote, which will close the question (since you are the author). Questions marked as duplicates are not deleted, but left as "signposts" to help future askers find the questions with the answers they need.

Comment: (If you need a certain amount of reputation to close-vote your own question, you might not see the option.)

Comment: @KiedLlaentenn Copy isn't needed for `Deref`, perhaps there's something else tripping you up?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I assume that they mean they have a variable like `foo: &Token` and want to do `*foo`, not actually implement `Deref` themselves. I agree that there's probably some better solution for the real problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster Good call, that makes sense.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes, that's what I was trying to do :)